# /data/log/error.log permission denied even though i set <chmod dir="${basedir}/../data" perm="777" includes="**/*"/>

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, ant, centos

I am facing this issue, my build.xml looks like this

```
    <chmod dir="${basedir}/" perm="777" />
    <chmod dir="${basedir}/logs" perm="777" />
    <chmod dir="${basedir}/../data" perm="777" includes="**/*"/>
```

But while loading the application, i face the below error

```
/data/log/error.log couldn't be opened in appended mode: failed to open stream: permission denied
```

i assume that the data directory have all the subdirectories and files assigned with permission 777 recursively using the below line

```
<chmod dir="${basedir}/../data" perm="777" includes="**/*"/>
```

**The directory permissions:**

```
[root@staging ~]# ls -la /data/builds/application/build-0.2246/unzipped/data/log/
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     38 Sep 26 15:38 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root    115 Sep 26 15:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 286437 Sep 27 06:25 error.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  88723 Sep 27 06:25 event.log
```

**What was expected:**
the data/log/error.log should have 777 permissions and shouldn't face any permission issues

**What did i try:**
When i face this issue, i had to manually give the 777 permissions using terminal command

Comment: *"i had to manually give the 777 permissions ..."* ... So it worked when you did it from terminal? I had expected it would also fail. The typical reason is that an upper level directory `/firstLevel` often is perms 755 or less, and is owned by a admin user. Don't know what it wont work in your build.xml. Good luck.

Comment: I recommend that you post some actual permissions (`ls -ld`) listings of the indivdual parent-child directories and indlcate the userID that runs your `build.xml`. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter, it works when i give 777 permissions from terminal, the upper level directories are ${basedir} and data which were given 777 permissions as shown in the build.xml.

Comment: @shelter, i have also updated "ls -la"

Comment: So you really have a root based `/data` dir with 777 perms? in any case without being there, I don't think I can help. There may be some other system security process that is blocking you. Highly recommend you delete here and repost to [unix.se] (Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code (and tools) problems. Your question seems to be about using and configuring *nix tools. ). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! @shellter, yes, the server is stage which is only accessed by VPN so we set 777 permissions with root for /data dir, will move this question to appropriate platform